# Where has Zend_Service_Twitter_Search gone?

Tags: php, zend-framework, twitter

I was just trying to use a simple twitter search with Zend_Service_Twitter_Search but the class is not in the Framework anymore. (v.1.12.3)

Documentation is still here: [ZF 1.12.3 documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.service.twitter.html#zend.service.twitter.search)

Has something changed in the api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup you're correct the documentation is wrong. check the [Api reference](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.12/) for current valid methods (like `searchTweets()`) and classes, it seems to be correct.

Comment: do you know any reasons for removing it? Seems like you have to authenticate now, even for a simple search.

Comment: Twitter completely overhauled their api.